# ADC6..7 pins not defined in avr-libc

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, atmega

I have an `atmega8-au` microcontroller and analog inputs on `ADC6` and `ADC7`

[image: atmega8au]

It is written in the datasheet that

> ADC7..6 serve as analog inputs to the A/D converter.
>   These pins are powered from the analog supply and serve as 10-bit ADC channels.

However, the pins are not defined in the `avr-libc 2.0.0-1` header files `iom8.h` or `iom8a.h`.

Comment: What is your question? What code  are you trying to use to read these pins? Take a look at some of the ADC tutorials and application notes. I think you'll find you're missing a lot of the process for reading from the ADC.

Comment: As any other AVR ADC input, they are selected by multiplexer. Check the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8159-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8A_datasheet.pdf)  paragraph 26.2 and on... MUXn channel selection bits of ADMUX register.

Comment: @Flanker thank you, that was what I wanted to hear. I'm setting them like `ADMUX |= (0 << MUX3) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX0);`